# Make external monitors wake up reliably with Xorg + autorandr

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, xorg

Setup:

- Dell XPS 9560 laptop connected to a Cable Matters Thunderbolt 3 dock to two LG 4k monitors.
- Linux (NixOS)
- i3 WM
- Autorandr using EDID to set proper screen layout on wake

When I plug in the dock to the laptop while it's screen is asleep, the external monitors wake up, then all three go black, and the two external monitors show "no signal".  I have to unplug and plug the dock back in to get them to properly wake up.

What I've found is that if I wake up the laptop screen first before plugging in the dock, everything works fine. What could be causing this?